# how to disable orangehrm leave cancellation

Tags: orangehrm

I want to ask if anyone here has a knowledge in customizing the OrangeHRM from sourceforge? What I have is the latest version.

What I want to do is disable the leave cancellation of the ESS users and only the Admin account has the right to cancel a filed leave. I have tried to post this question in their forum but somehow they do not provide some support or answers to the questions and somehow the existing answers was outdated.

Than You and hopping that my concerns would be answered.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: The one that I am using was the latest one which is 3.2